# Motion end Path to shape position in slide

Tags: vba, path, powerpoint, motion

I wanted to refer end point to shape position in slide

```
Dim Shape As Shape
Set Shape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("target")

Path = "M 0 0 L " &  Shape.Left  & " " & Shape.Top & " E"
```

How can I get it right?
Please help

Comment: You're trying to set an OOXML parameter with VBA. Microsoft has not provided any way to do that. Here's my article on how to edit OOXML with VBA. It includes a free download of code to make it possible: https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2021/03/edit-ooxml-with-vba-cool-code/